# Waterfall in ComponentDialogs

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am having problems implementing `WaterfallDialogs` in `ComponentDialogs` trigered by LUIS in the `BotFramework V4.2`. After the first step, the dialog does not continue the Waterfall.
I don't really understand what should be the correct approach to persist the `ComponentDialog`: save the `ConversationState`? set the `step.context`? I've tried both but none worked for me so far

This is my code for bot.js, where I have a LUIS instance to act as an orchestrator between dialogs:

```
async onTurn(turnContext) {
...
switch (dialogResult.status) {
   case DialogTurnStatus.empty:
      // Call to LUIS recognizer to get intent + entities
      const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(dc.context);
      const topIntent = results.luisResult.topScoringIntent;

      switch (topIntent.intent) {
          case FMM_INTENT:
              return await dc.beginDialog(FeedbackDialog.Name);
          ...
      }
   case DialogTurnStatus.waiting:
      // The active dialog is waiting for a response from the user, so do nothing
       break;
...
}
```

And this is my code por FeedbackDialog.js where I have the logic of the `WaterfallDialog` with `Prompts`:

```
module.exports = {
FeedbackDialog: class extends ComponentDialog {
    static get Name() { return DIALOG_NAME; }
    constructor(conversationState, botConfig, feedbackStateAccessor, dialogId) {
        (dialogId === undefined) ? super(DIALOG_NAME) : super(dialogId);

        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.feedbackStateAccessor = feedbackStateAccessor;

        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(FBK_EVAL, [
            this.feedbackPrompt.bind(this),
            this.feedbackEvaluation.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(FBK_PROMPT));
    }

    async feedbackPrompt(step) {
        let fmmState = await this.feedbackStateAccessor.get(step.context);
        if (fmmState === undefined) {
            await this.feedbackStateAccessor.set(step.context);
            //opciones válidas, las mayúsculas las detecta también
            const options = ['',''];
            return await step.prompt(FBK_PROMPT, {
                prompt: `¿Te ha resultado útil la respuesta?`,
                retryPrompt: `¿Qué te ha parecido la respuesta?`,
                choices: options
            });
        }
    }

    async feedbackEvaluation(step) {
        let fmmState = await this.feedbackStateAccessor.get(step.context);
        if (fmmState === undefined && step.result){
            if (step.result == ''){
                await step.context.sendActivity("¡Gracias por el feedback!");
                return await step.endDialog();
            }else {
                await step.context.sendActivity("¡Revisaremos tu pregunta para seguir mejorando!");
                return await this.conversationState.saveChanges(step.context);
            }             
        } else {
            return await step.next();
            //next steps omitted since the code doesn't reach this step
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve but if you're using a ChoicePrompt I believe the step result comes back into a value key, i.e. instead of

```
if (step.result == '')
```

try

```
if (step.result.value === '')
```

Then you can send a message back to the user and end the dialog and it should be fine:

```
await step.context.sendActivity("¡Gracias por el feedback!");
return step.endDialog();
```

or

```
await step.context.sendActivity("¡Revisaremos tu pregunta para seguir mejorando!");
return step.endDialog();
```

Also, remember to initialise the dialog correctly, i.e. in your bot file:

```
const { FeedbackDialog } = require('path/to/feedbackDialog')
const FEEDBACK_DIALOG = 'FeedbackDialog'
const FEEDBACK_PROPERTY = 'feedbackProperty'
```

and in the bot constructor (I use userState for state accessors, not conversation state):

```
this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState)
this.feedbackAccessor = userState.createProperty(FEEDBACK_PROPERTY)
this.dialogs.add(new FeedbackDialog(
  FEEDBACK_DIALOG,
  this.feedbackAccessor
))
```

then call it as:

```
await dc.beginDialog(FEEDBACK_DIALOG);
```

Comment: Thank you @Naadof, my problem was using ConversationState for state accessors. I changed to UserState and everything works fine now. As for the `ChoicePrompt`, I am not sure if it is the best approach, but `step.result` works fine in case someone is having the same question